# Role of data-role attribute in html markup

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am new to Kendo UI library. When going through the tutorial i found the following declaration

```
<input id="JoiningDate" data-role="datepicker"/>
```

could you please explain ,what is the role of data-role attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called declarative initialization.

Inside this attribute ,You are specifying the type of Widget you want to use (in this case it is a datepicker widget).

You can either use regular markup

```
<input id="JoiningDate" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function ()
 {
    $("#JoiningDate").KendoDatePicker();
});
</script>
```

(or)

```
<input id="JoiningDate" data-role="datepicker"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function ()
 {
    kendo.init($("#JoiningDate"));
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In summary:

"The value of the role data attribute is the name of the widget in lower case e.g. "autocomplete", "dropdownlist" etc."

You can find info here:

http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/data-attribute-initialization#example---initialize-a-kendo-ui-widget-using-a-data-attributes